# Why translating a program from one high-level programming language directly into another is difficult?

Tags: programming-languages, compilers

I am looking for a better explanation (research level, papers) to answer:

**Why translating a program from one high-level programming language directly into another is difficult?**

Note: When I say difficult I don't mean "hard" - i.e. I am not taking about computational complexity here simply because I am unaware of such results, but you are very much welcome to correct my ignorance.

I understand that at the core of the argument can say something like one-to-one mapping for such translation simply does not exists.

In general, I am not comfortable with terminology used in my own question.

We know from text books: *Low-level language* - each command or object of the language has one-to-one mapping to CPU commands (e.g. Assembler). All other languages are *High-level*.

Is there a way to reformulate the question into FSA formalism like with  [regular languges](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language), or some other formalism. But I don't think Church–Turing thesis can help here - it is not about computability or existence of a proof.

PS

My motivation is very simple - I want to discuss/answer how difficult is such a problem for example in translating PHP to Java. Please note that direct translation is indeed a mapping of language commands or objects  (e.g. HipHop does not qualify).

---

Probably any **pragmatic solution** would be indirect translation, i.e. in order to (partially) convert a program P written in high-level language A into a high-level language B:

1. (complexity lowering) convert codebase of program P from A to low or inter-mediate level language C
2. (shared codebase) resue parts of converted codebase of program P by calling commands in low or inter-mediate level language C from high level language B

Comment: do you really believe you should ask this (if you should at all, since this is well pretty much more of a rhetoric statement rather than question) at Programmers SE.

Comment: I am happy to change or move the question as you have suggested. But I have a better chance of getting a CS answer here.

Comment: This question I got from a reviewer on a "computaional" paper.

Comment: Your question works off the assumption that this task *is* hard. I don't know, is it? I wouldn't think so. (You don't require the result to be idiomatic or anything.)

Comment: By the way, by your definition of "low-level", x86 assembly is a high-level language these days. I think you need a better definition.

Comment: *Why* do you want to translate between the languages? I'm asking because acceptable translation strategies could differ based on the answer.

Comment: Translating between wildly different languages is *hard*, translating between similar languages is rather easy. One advantage of translating to a high level language is that you can leverage that one.Take a look at e.g. RATFOR: it translated a C-like language into FORTRAN, the preprocessor was quite simple. The resulting FORTRAN program can then be compiled on any machine having a FORTRAN compiler, and that one did all the heavy lifting of generating good code, fighting the local operating system, and all those messy details.

Comment: I don't understand why you ask for a research-level answer when a non-research-level answer would be perfectly satisfactory.  I think reading a compiler textbook would be enough to give some sense of why it's hard: after all, it takes an entire textbook to even scratch the surface of the subject!  Or, you could read the source code of a commercially deployed compiler (e.g., llvm) -- we're talking about hundreds of thousands of lines of code.  If it was easy to get good performance, they wouldn't be anywhere so complex.

Comment: What makes this hard is usually the other requirements, like requirements for good performance.  If you don't care about performance, it's probably not super hard.  Your question doesn't state whether you care about things like performance, ability to link/interface with other Java code, and so on.  One way to demonstrate that this is hard is by doing a literature search to find all prior research papers that try to attempt something of this sort, and surveying the prior work.  Have you done that?  If you're trying to publish a paper on the subject that's something you need to do anyway!

Comment: Based on the comments and answers you're getting so far, let me encourage you to edit the question to clarify your requirements: do you require good/near-optimal performance?  do you require that the output code be human-readable or human-maintainable?  do you require support for all of the libraries and APIs that might be accessible in the source language (PHP) and ability to translate code that uses them?  The answers will depend heavily on this information.

Comment: there is probably some decent question in all this but its too theoretical right now. what application is to be ported? what is the _rationale_ for the porting? you mention PHP to Java. is it to attempt to achieve _improved_ performance? porting always is done with some kind of end-goal in mind, its a "biting of the bullet" with a later payoff. fyi, two areas where a lot of porting goes on (across languages/ platforms): mobile apps, and games.

Comment: Take @D.W. last comment with care: changing the question so that answers get invalidate is not nice. In such cases, it's better to post a new question.

Comment: Raphael has a good point.  It's an unfortunate situation to have a vague/ambiguous question, with different answers that interpret the question differently.  It would be better to be clear from the start, but perhaps at this point the best you can do is use this to ask a new question that is more specific and focused.

Comment: Dear all, the question does require clarification. I will apply an **edit** to answer on goals of translation (@D.W. comment). I see already that my point about **direct** (ASM -> machione code) vs. **indirect** (C++ -> LLVM -> Java) translation has been completely ignored. I do care in how difficult is a direct translation for high level languages.

Comment: @Raphael I don't use term hard as in CS sense as in hard computational problem or being computationally hard in algorithmic sense. I use term difficult (which is not reserved by any CS terminology) to indicate that there is no solution if form of software for one step (**direct**) translating every given program or even every given expression between high level languages. Another analogy in computational linguistics is so called statistical machine translation of natural languages: one produces a probabilistic mapping A <-> B, no translation in any third (lower complexity language).

Comment: Your premise that direct is different from indirect does not seem valid to me.  Even compilers that you think are direct are probably internally actually doing some indirect translation (e.g., compile to internal representation or intermediate language, then go from there to the final output).  Even an assembler might have such a structure.  In other words, one-step/direct translation does not seem like a well-defined concept.

Answer (score 3):

The task *is* simple. Here are two naive strategies.

Say we want to compile from A to B.

1. Pick a language C for which you have a compiler A $\to$ C and an interpreter for $C$ in $B$.

   Create a new program in B that includes the compilate (in C) as string and the code of the interpreter.
2. Compile code in A to machine code or intermediate language. Translate line by line to B.

Both give horrible programs -- but you did not require anything fancy.

The more theoretical answer is: we know that effective (i.e. Turing-computable) compilers exist between any two Turing-complete languages, since such define nothing but an [admissible numbering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Admissible_numbering).

Comment: This assumes you can implement the semantics of C in B. Also this assumes that C can be interpreted.

What if language A is "C++", and B is Java ~ This transformation is not possible without a lot of 'proof by hand waving'.

Comment: @roscoe_casita These are not assumptions, but certainties (as long as all three languages are Turing-complete, which I guess goes without saying). These language can all do *exactly* the same, and we even *know* that we have computable compilers. Oh, I have to add that.

Comment: strictly speaking, the first one is an assumption because programming languages can do things that turing machines can't. you can't translate java into brainfuck, even though both are turing-complete, because java can make your computer do things like connect to the internet or play a sound. But I agree with the spirit of your answer entirely, and of I can't think of a modern, general-purpose language that can't make a normal computer do everything the hardware is capable of up to the user's ability to tell the difference

Answer (score 2):

here are two examples of scientific literature on porting projects, the 1st is a large Phd thesis that includes much detail on the intricacies/ difficulties, many of which would apply to different projects, its a C++ to java analysis for a large software system. the difficulties that would be encountered with porting tends to vary by project/ language and is oriented around the rationale for the port. often porting is to achieve better performance, and then the challenge is actually achieving it.

you also mention PHP to Java. a description of a similar project of converting Ruby (also a dynamic scripting language) to Java that happened at Twitter may be useful. there are a huge variety of porting projects that occur and it would be difficult to make generalizations. there is much more literature on eg attempting to compare language performance on standard problems etc.

- [Tools, techniques, and trade-offs when porting large
  software systems to new environments](http://www.bth.se/people/ska/phd-ska-a4.pdf) / Simon K˚agstr¨om
- [A case study on porting scientific applications to GPU/CUDA](http://epacis.net/jcis/PDF_JCIS/JCIS11-art.27.pdf)/ Delgado,  Gazolla, Clua, Sadjadi
- [The Second Coming of Java: A Relic Returns to Rule Web](http://www.wired.com/2013/09/the-second-coming-of-java/) / Wired

Answer (score 1):

I think that when doing the translation, you're going to encounter two main difficulties (read: things that could require lots of work):

1. High level languages tend to have lots of features. And even if two languages have a similar feature, they tend to work slightly differently. So, for each feature in the source language (and possibly for each edge case of that feature), you will need to find translation to the target language.

   For example, PHP is dynamically typed, Java statically typed. So, to translate from PHP to Java, you would somehow need to simulate PHP's dynamic typing in Java.
2. Languages often come with large standard libraries/frameworks/runtimes, which often aren't completely written in the language itself (so you can't just use the translator on them).

Comment: You can define language features as semantics, thus your comparing the semantics of one language to another, to find similarity.

If there is not a direct match, then semantic translation from S1 to S2 need to be done for any kind of conversion.

Answer (score 0):

A Simple example of this is trying to show equivalence in C to OCaml.

The features of pointers are not even a language feature in OCaml, and Pattern matching of OCaml is not a feature of C.

This is a simplistic example, but the fundamental semantics of the languages are  different.

There are many languages that a 'simple' translation will suffice:  Java <=> C#, or Scheme <=> Lisp.

We can show they are all equivalent to a Turing machine, but this does not give you a practical translation.

Comment: Are you sure translating between C# generics and Java generics can be considered simple?

Comment: This entirely depends on the exact language semantics, they may look and feel very similar, and perhaps even produce the same results, but the semantics would show they are not the same.

Thus there is no 'easy' solution in the general case.